# Highcharts Export server - Can't generate image using --options

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to generate an image using local NodeJS (6.11) server and [Highcharts export server](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server)

I use the sample `--options` parameters from a [Highcharts example page](http://export.highcharts.com/), where you can play around with the input data.

I have installed a Highcharts export server with NPM, created the JSON file in my project folder and copypasted the contents from Highcharts website. Then I saved it and run the following command on the local server:

```
highcharts-export-server --outfile output.png --infile input.json
```

which works great and created a .png file with the chart.

But then I try to generate a chart using the `--instr` or `--options` flags, passing the JSON as inline options, but all I get is a chart with

```
 **`SyntaxError: Expected token '}'`**
```

printed on it.

The exact command, which I'm running in my NPM CLI looks like this:

```
highcharts-export-server --outfile chart.png --instr {"constr":"Chart","type":"png","title":{"text":"Steep Chart"},"options":{"xAxis":["categories","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]]},"series":[{"data":[1,3,2,4],"type":"line"},{"data":[5,3,4,2],"type":"line"}]
```

Enabling logs didn't do it for me, as PhantomJS shows no errors whatsoever, even with the verbose (4) logging mode. I assume the problem may be that provided JSON is an object, while the only accepted data type for `--instr` and `--options` is a string, but I'm not sure if I am correct and how to make it work.

Any thoughts? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Nice detailed first question. Hope you find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Try wrapping your json in single quotes `<your josn>`

Comment: That doesn't work, gives "The syntax of the command is incorrect", but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please notice that `constr` and `type` are not valid Highcharts options. All options and their structure can be found in the **API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/

Make sure that all brackets are enclosed properly and options structure is maintained. `options` is not a Highcharts option. Also you should assign a JSON or an array of JSONs to `xAxis` property (not an array of Strings).

Change all quotes inside the options string to a single ones. Surround the whole string using double quotes.

**This code worked for me:**

```
highcharts-export-server --outfile chart.png --instr "{'title':{'text':'Steep Chart'},'xAxis':{'categories': ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']},'series':[{'data':[1,3,2,4],'type':'line'},{'data':[5,3,4,2],'type':'line'}]}"
```